# Forming a HTML string in Controller and Passing it to View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

In controller I want to form a message for example

> " 7 results found - Do something now "

And I want it to show that text in the View but I want the first part to be bold so like "**7 results found** - Do something now" so when I create my string in controller I wrap that part around `<b>` tags but it doesn't work! It is showing the exact string with `<b>` in the view.  How should I do this?

Comment: Try using TagBuilder

Answer (score 1):

To display HTML in Razor you can use:

```
@Html.Raw(Model.Property)
```

This will handle HTML tags for you.

Of course you can also add here string from ViewBag, Resources or just hard coded.

Answer (score 1):

Using Html.Raw allows you to output text containing html elements.
@Html.Raw("**7 results found** - Do something now")